# Using Mac log time find out good hours and bad hours in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my input table: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uFX7.png) I Need to get Machine Good hours and bad hours using sql queries. I am tried this query.

```
 select  machinename,
               min(case when status = 'Good' then logtime end) as good
        ,       max(case when status = 'Bad' then logtime end) as bad
        ,       cast(min(logtime ) as date) as date
        from    Machine_proxy_report
        group by
                machinename,cast(log_time as date);
```

I Need to get output like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POayC.png)

| Machinename | status | logtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mac1 | good | 2024-03-07 01:10:00 |
| Mac1 | good | 2024-03-07 02:15:00 |
| Mac1 | good | 2024-03-07 03:20:00 |
| Mac1 | bad | 2024-03-07 04:10:00 |
| Mac1 | good | 2024-03-07 05:10:00 |
| Mac1 | good | 2024-03-07 11:10:00 |
| Mac1 | bad | 2024-03-07 15:10:00 |
| Mac1 | good | 2024-03-07 16:10:00 |
| Mac1 | good | 2024-03-07 23:10:00 |

Comment: post the data in the question instead

Comment: Machinename|status|logtime
Mac1|good|2024-03-07 01:10:00
Mac1|good|2024-03-07 02:15:00
Mac1|good|2024-03-07 03:20:00
Mac1|bad|2024-03-07 04:10:00
Mac1|good|2024-03-07 05:10:00
Mac1|good|2024-03-07 11:10:00
Mac1|bad|2024-03-07 15:10:00
Mac1|good|2024-03-07 16:10:00
Mac1|good|2024-03-07 23:10:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using the window function `lead() over()` ,`datediff()` and `PIVOT`

**Note:**  No logic for spanning days (i.e. midnight).  Not clear if required.

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select Date  = convert(date,logtime)
              ,MachineName
              ,Status
              ,Hours = datediff(hour,logtime,lead(logtime,1) over (partition by MachineName order by LogTime))
         From YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot ( sum(Hours) for Status in ([Good],[Bad]) ) pvt
```

**Results**

```
Date        MachineName Good    Bad
2024-07-03  Mac1        20      2
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example of the expected result, you do not have a shown `date`. In the example query, you have a grouping by date. In my example, grouping by date is performed, as well as additional calculations for ranges going through midnight.

Period ('2024-03-07 23:10:00')->('2024-03-08 03:10:00') divided to

('2024-03-07 23:10:00')->('2024-03-07 23:59:59')  date '2024-03-07'
('2024-03-08 00:00:00')->('2024-03-08 03:10:00')  date '2024-03-08'

See example

```
select Machine,logDate
  ,sum(case when Status='good' then elong end) GoodLong
  ,sum(case when Status='bad' then elong end) BadLong
  ,round(cast(sum(case when Status='good' then elong end) as float)/3600.0,4) GoodLongH
  ,round(cast(sum(case when Status='bad' then elong end) as float)/3600.0,4) BadLongH
from(
  select *,cast(logtime as date) LogDate
    ,datediff(s,logtime,lead(logtime,1,logtime)over(order by logtime)) elong
 from( -- for over-midnight periods
   select Machine,  Status,n
    ,case  when n=1 and logDate<>nextDate then 
       cast(nextDate as datetime)
     else logTime
     end LogTime 
    ,case when n=0 and logDate<>nextDate then dateadd(s,-1,cast(nextDate as datetime))
     else nextTime
     end nextTime
   from(
     select *
       ,cast(logtime as date) logDate
       ,lead(logtime,1,logtime)over(order by logtime) nextTime
       ,cast(lead(logtime,1,logtime)over(order by logtime) as date) nextDate
     from Logwork) a
     left join (select 0 n union all select 1 )t(n)
        on (n=0  ) or (n=1 and logDate<>nextDate )
   )b
 )с
group by Machine,LogDate
```

with test data, including datetime thru midnight

```
insert into LogWork values
 ('Mac1','good','2024-03-07 1:10:05')
,('Mac1','good','2024-03-07 2:15:00') 
,('Mac1','good','2024-03-07 3:20:00') 
,('Mac1','bad','2024-03-07 4:10:00') 
,('Mac1','good','2024-03-07 5:10:00') 
,('Mac1','good','2024-03-07 11:10:00') 
,('Mac1','bad','2024-03-07 15:10:00') 
,('Mac1','good','2024-03-07 16:10:00') 
,('Mac1','good','2024-03-07 23:10:00')
,('Mac1','bad','2024-03-08 03:10:00')
,('Mac1','good','2024-03-08 05:10:00')
;
```

Output

| Machine | logDate | GoodLong | BadLong | GoodLongH | BadLongH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mac1 | 2024-03-07 | 74995 | 7200 | 20.8319 | 2 |
| Mac1 | 2024-03-08 | 11400 | 7200 | 3.1667 | 2 |

Subquery for calculating thru-midnight output

| Machine | Status | n | LogTime | nextTime | LogDate | elong |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mac1 | good | 0 | 2024-03-07 01:10:05.000 | 2024-03-07 02:15:00.000 | 2024-03-07 | 3895 |
| Mac1 | good | 0 | 2024-03-07 02:15:00.000 | 2024-03-07 03:20:00.000 | 2024-03-07 | 3900 |
| Mac1 | good | 0 | 2024-03-07 03:20:00.000 | 2024-03-07 04:10:00.000 | 2024-03-07 | 3000 |
| Mac1 | bad | 0 | 2024-03-07 04:10:00.000 | 2024-03-07 05:10:00.000 | 2024-03-07 | 3600 |
| Mac1 | good | 0 | 2024-03-07 05:10:00.000 | 2024-03-07 11:10:00.000 | 2024-03-07 | 21600 |
| Mac1 | good | 0 | 2024-03-07 11:10:00.000 | 2024-03-07 15:10:00.000 | 2024-03-07 | 14400 |
| Mac1 | bad | 0 | 2024-03-07 15:10:00.000 | 2024-03-07 16:10:00.000 | 2024-03-07 | 3600 |
| Mac1 | good | 0 | 2024-03-07 16:10:00.000 | 2024-03-07 23:10:00.000 | 2024-03-07 | 25200 |
| Mac1 | good | 0 | 2024-03-07 23:10:00.000 | 2024-03-07 23:59:59.000 | 2024-03-07 | 3000 |
| Mac1 | good | 1 | 2024-03-08 00:00:00.000 | 2024-03-08 03:10:00.000 | 2024-03-08 | 11400 |
| Mac1 | bad | 0 | 2024-03-08 03:10:00.000 | 2024-03-08 05:10:00.000 | 2024-03-08 | 7200 |
| Mac1 | good | 0 | 2024-03-08 05:10:00.000 | 2024-03-08 05:10:00.000 | 2024-03-08 | 0 |